# Width of a k-ary tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I need to find the width of a k-ary tree, where the width is the maximum number of nodes at any level. I've to do it in C++. I've thought about a modified version of a BFS but without any luck.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Hi I am trying to implement k-array tree whose output is in the form of adjacent matrix using Java. Input parameters are k=number of child for each node and d= depth of tree. given this parameter I am to generate adjacent matrix of the tree. I saw github and was not able to follow.can you please guide me to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to traverse the tree and track node depth as you do so.  Every time you encounter a node, you can update a counter associated with that depth of that node.  Once you're done, you can then find the depth with the highest total value, then return that.

In pseudocode:

```
int treeWidth(Node* root) {
    unordered_map<int, int> levelFreqs;
    recFindDepths(root, levelFreqs, 0);

    int maxCount = -1;
    for (auto& keyValue: levelFreqs) {
        maxCount = max(maxCount, keyValue.second);
    }
    return maxCount;
}

void recFindDepths(Node* root, unordered_map<int, int>& levelFreqs,
                   int depth) {
    if (!root) return;

    levelFreqs[depth]++;
    for (each child) {
        recFindDepths(child, levelFreqs, depth + 1);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The right solution! Thanks! I've used an array rather than an unordered_map cause we can't use it (because of we're studying this kind of data structure ;)

Comment: This is what i've done. http://pastebin.com/7fU7JBtN And it works! ;) Thanks again, very helpful.

Comment: Hi I am trying to implement k-array tree whose output is in the form of adjacent matrix using Java. Input parameters are k=number of child for each node and d= depth of tree. given this parameter I am to generate adjacent matrix of the tree. I saw github and was not able to follow.can you please guide me to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum number should be k^depth, where the root is depth==0.  Do you mean the maximum in use?

Comment: I think it really depends on the shape of the tree - if the tree isn't full, then a middle layer might be fuller than the bottom layer.